# Monte Screen Recorder Suddenly Not Working. Blank Videos

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, vlc, screen-recording

I was previously using the MonteScreenRecorder to record test executions. I had no issues a week ago when my last success video was recorded. Suddenly the videos are recording blank now. I run the test...the video is added to the folder but when I try to watch it nothing happens. It doesn't load or start. It's just blank.

Here's my Screen Recorder Class:

```
public class ScreenRecorderUtil extends ScreenRecorder {

 public static ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;
 public String name;
 public ScreenRecorderUtil(GraphicsConfiguration cfg, Rectangle captureArea, Format fileFormat,
   Format screenFormat, Format mouseFormat, Format audioFormat, File movieFolder, String name)
     throws IOException, AWTException {
  super(cfg, captureArea, fileFormat, screenFormat, mouseFormat, audioFormat, movieFolder);
  this.name = name;
 }

 @Override
 protected File createMovieFile(Format fileFormat) throws IOException {

  if (!movieFolder.exists()) {
   movieFolder.mkdirs();
  } else if (!movieFolder.isDirectory()) {
   throw new IOException("\"" + movieFolder + "\" is not a directory.");
  }
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
  return new File(movieFolder,
    name + "-" + dateFormat.format(new Date()) + "." + Registry.getInstance().getExtension(fileFormat));
 }

 public static void startRecord(String methodName) throws Exception {
  File file = new File("./reports-recordings/");
  Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  int width = screenSize.width;
  int height = screenSize.height;

  Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

  GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().
    getDefaultScreenDevice()
    .getDefaultConfiguration();
  screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorderUtil(gc, captureSize,
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
      CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE, DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey,
      Rational.valueOf(15), QualityKey, 1.0f, KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black", FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
    null, file, methodName);
  screenRecorder.start();
 }

 public static void stopRecord() throws Exception {
  screenRecorder.stop();
 }
}
```

This is my Base Class where I start and end recording:

public abstract class BaseTest extends DriverUtil {

```
@BeforeMethod
protected static void openDriver() throws Exception {
    DriverUtil.openBrowser();
    ScreenRecorderUtil.startRecord("TestRecording");
}

@AfterMethod
protected static void cleanUp() throws Exception {
    DriverUtil.closeBrowser();
    ScreenRecorderUtil.stopRecord();
}

protected void LOG(String message) {
    TestListener.getTestSection().info(message);
}

protected void IMG(String message) {
    String screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) UIActions.driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
    TestListener.getTestSection().addScreenCaptureFromBase64String(screenshot, message);
}
```

}

The Dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I'd like to know too... All I see is my background